# proxy.golang.org: failed to verify certificate

Tags: docker, go, caddy

When trying to build caddy docker image (caddy:2.7) the following command failed with error :

`go: github.com/caddyserver/caddy/v2@v2.7.6: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/caddyserver/caddy/v2/@v/v2.7.6.info": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

The command:

```
RUN xcaddy build \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure/caddy \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain/caddy
```

My complete Dockerfile

```
ARG CADDY_VERSION=2.7

FROM caddy:${CADDY_VERSION}-builder-alpine AS caddy_builder

RUN xcaddy build \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure/caddy \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain/caddy

FROM caddy:${CADDY_VERSION} AS caddy

WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY --from=dunglas/mercure:v0.11 /srv/public /srv/mercure-assets/
COPY --from=caddy_builder /usr/bin/caddy /usr/bin/caddy
COPY docker/caddy/Caddyfile /etc/caddy/Caddyfile
```

Trying to build the caddy image in local:
`docker build -f Dockerfile --target caddy .`

Expected successful build.

Comment: First, have you checked what CA signs the certificate to which requests to that address come back?

Comment: The first thing to check is whether the thing the error reports _is true_ -- in this case, meaning that someone is running a man-in-the-middle attack on you. (If you're behind a corporate proxy, that may even be intentional as part of a "security measure").

Comment: (The next question is whether Go -- and in particular, the version of Go that `caddy:2.7-builder-alpine` bundles in -- pins a CA for proxy.golang.org; if it does, then if that certificate needs to be replaced, versions of Go so old as to have a prior certificate pinned will be unable to connect to the service; if it doesn't, then the set of root CAs included that Alpine image needs to be up-to-date enough to recognize the current signing CA as valid, so _eventually_ it's normal/expected for the image to stop working against newer public servers).

Comment: ...a subset of these questions can be answered if someone else tries to build the Dockerfile you've provided here; I'm not equipped to be that someone right now.

Comment: (Mind, you _can_ disable GOPROXY, but GOPROXY -- as the proxy maintains a tamper-resistent history of valid hashes of old releases of Go libraries to make in-place modifications detectable  -- is a security measure, and turning off security measures _when those security measures are preventing you from doing something unsafe_ is thus disabling them when they're most needed; it's much, _much_ better to spend the time to get to the bottom of the immediate trigger).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Go does not pin a CA, though it's possible the image's OS trusted CA store could be outdated.

Comment: Yup -- so in that case, the OP should presumably rebuild `caddy:2.7-builder-alpine` against a newer alpine.

Comment: BTW, re: recent edit, see [Why are users removing "thank you"s from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions) on [meta].

Comment: You could also report this as a bug to whomever is responsible for maintaining the `caddy:2.7-builder-alpine` Docker image.

Comment: I tried your Dockerfile with a [dummy Caddyfile](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile) - the image was built without issues. Check your network configuration. Try `openssl s_client -connect proxy.golang.org:443 < /dev/null` - the root certificate should be `C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1`